# App engine mapreduce job made me go over quota

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

For my first mapreduce project, using Google App Engine, Python version, I implemented a simple counter:

```
def process(entity):
    yield op.counters.Increment("counter1")
```

Partway through the run, I went over quota. When my quota gets reset tomorrow, will it pick up where it left off, and eventually produce the final result, or do I need enough quota do perform the whole task, without being interrupted in this way?

This is only practice. For my "real" mapreduce job, I'm going to be modifying each entry in my database table. Is there some good some way to save my table data, in case something goes awry?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapreduce counters are stored in the datastore, so they will persist even if you pause the mapreduce for an extended period of time.

Likewise, modifications made in a mapreduce are executed in batches at regular intervals; changes you make are applied more or less immediately.

Comment: Yup. Looks like it finished today.So I guess it was a "pause", as oppose to a "kill".